# Adding new parameter to wordpress loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code which is missing a part in order to determine which '`post`' to use.

**html**

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php 
            $postAlign = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'postType', true );

            if ( $postAlign == 'Lsection' ) {
                get_template_part( 'article' , 'Lsection' );     
            }
            else {
                get_template_part( 'article' , 'Rsection' );   
            }
            else {
                get_template_part( 'article' , 'Fsection' );   
            }
        ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

What I want is 
if the post has postAlign of '**Lsection**' use `article-Lsection.php`, 
if the post has postAlign of '**Rsection**' use `article-Rsection.php`, 
if the post has postAlign of '**Fsection**' use `article-Fsection.php`

I know I there must be a else if or some similar function invloved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `else` block should not follow another `else` block. See the modified `if-else if` blocks below. For more information about formatting control structures, refer to the [php.net](http://php.net) page: [elseif/else if](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php)

```
if ( $postAlign == 'Lsection' ) {
    get_template_part( 'article' , 'Lsection' );     
}
else if ($postAlign == 'Rsection') {
    get_template_part( 'article' , 'Rsection' );   
}
else {
    get_template_part( 'article' , 'Fsection' );   
}
```

You could also use a [`switch`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement - e.g.:

```
switch($postAlign) {
    case 'Lsection':
    case 'Rsection':
        get_template_part( 'article' , $postAlign );     
        break;
    default:
        get_template_part( 'article' , 'Fsection' );   
        break;
}
```

Or just simplify it even more:

```
if ( $postAlign == 'Lsection' || $postAlign == 'Rsection') {
    get_template_part( 'article' , $postAlign );     
}
else {
    get_template_part( 'article' , 'Fsection' );   
}
```

Also, is there a reason you are using the [alternate syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) and excess closing/opening php tags? You should be able to simplify it, like this:

```
<?php 
//if ( have_posts() ) { //
   while ( have_posts() ) {
         the_post();
         $postAlign = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'postType', true );

        if ( $postAlign == 'Lsection' || $postAlign == 'Rsection') {
            get_template_part( 'article' , $postAlign );     
        }
        else {
            get_template_part( 'article' , 'Fsection' );   
        }
    }//end while
//}//end if
 //only need one closing php tag down here:
?>
```

**Edit:**
To demonstrate this, see [this PHPfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/b28b-7fgs). Feel free to create an account there and play with the code. Notice that it calls `get_templatepart()` with the various 2nd parameters based on the value of `$postAlign`.

Comment: Nice - please also see the extra code suggestion I added at the bottom to simplify the entire code

Comment: Still running into some problem where despite using deferent postAlign (Lsection, etc) in my wordpress admin they all use article-Fsection

Comment: Where does '$postAlign' get set and what is that variable when you 'var_dump()' it?

Comment: @user3550879 I added a link to [an example I made on phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/y0qg-xyth)

Comment: perfect, I had to change postType to postAlign